# hyperledger fabric chaincode deploy error

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

My peer node reported this error：
[image]

this is my configtx.yaml:

```
Organizations:
  - &ebao
    Name: ebao 
    ID: ebaoMSP 
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ebao.com/msp 


  - &tk
    Name: tk
    ID: tkMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/tk.com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: peer0.tk.com
        Port: 7051



  - &cs
    Name: cs
    ID: csMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/cs.com/msp
    AnchorPeers: 
      - Host: peer0.cs.com
        Port: 7051

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  
  OrdererType: solo 
  Addresses: 
    - orderer.ebao.com:7050
  BatchTimeout: 2s 
  BatchSize: 
    MaxMessageCount: 10 
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB 
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB 
  Organizations:




Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:

Profiles:
  TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *ebao
    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
          - *tk
          - *cs

  TwoOrgsChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *tk
        - *cs
```

I don't know where the problem is,the chaincode has been installed,but would report this error when 'peer chaincode invoke': 
docker exec cli bash -c "$tkPeer0Cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.ebao.com:7050 -C appchannel -n fabric-realty -l golang -v 1.0.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "AND ('tkMSP.client','csMSP.client')""

Answer (score 0):

try to use below command

docker exec cli bash -c "$tkPeer0Cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.ebao.com:7050 -C appchannel -n fabric-realty -l golang -v 1.0.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "AND ('tkMSP.peer','csMSP.peer')""